# how to query names of friends from a friend's table

Tags: mysql

Given the following table, I'm trying to write a query that will return the names of user 104's friends.

MYSQL TABLE friends

```
id | requester | requestee | status
--------------------------------------
1  | 140       | 104       | 'friends'
2  | 104       | 151       | 'friends'
```

I tried this but it's not quite right because it returns the name of user 140 (which is correct) and the name of user 104 (which is incorrect - I wanted the name of user 151).  I realize part of my problem is due to the "ON f.requester = u.id", but I'm not sure how to write the query to get what I want.

```
SELECT u.name
FROM users u
INNER JOIN friends f ON f.requester = u.id
WHERE (
f.requester =104
AND STATUS = 'friends'
)
OR (
f.requestee =104
AND STATUS = 'friends'
)
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

**UPDATE:** I also tried making a "bigger query" and using PHP to extract what I need.  This sort of works but I'm only able to get the user IDs so far.
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `friends` WHERE requester='$userid' OR requestee='$userid'
    AND status='friends'";
    $results = mysql_query($query)
     or die(mysql_error());

```
$count = 0;
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
  $count++;
  if ( !is_null($row['requester']) ) {
    $requester = $row['requester'];
    $requestee = $row['requestee'];
    if($requester == $userid)
      echo $requestee . "<br /><br />";
    else
      echo $requester . "<br /><br />";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're basically looking at two queries - one where 104 is the requester and the other where 104 is the requestee. A `UNION` query can combine these, so that you can use the result in a join or a sub select.

```
SELECT u.name
FROM users u
WHERE u.id IN (
    SELECT requester as friendId
    FROM friends
    WHERE requestee = 104
    AND STATUS = 'friends'
    UNION
    SELECT requestee as friendId
    FROM friends
    WHERE requester = 104
    AND STATUS = 'friends'
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I tried the query and got an error on the UNION: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION
    (SELECT requestee as friendId
    FROM friends
    WHERE requester = 1' at line 8

Comment: I just had to remove the parenthesis surrounding the SELECTS and it works like a charm!  Thanks!

Comment: I tried editing your response to remove the paranthesis but I don't have sufficient privileges.  Can you edit it so I can mark the answer as good?

Comment: Note to self: Don't post answers as you're leaving the office :-)